Eclipse ADT with Android 14 SDK?
I have an app that works with any Android starting from 2.3.3
I did it on Windows XP with Eclipse Luna with ADT.
Now Google Play store requires the app to target the Android 14
SDK Manager in Eclipse does not load the Android 14 SDK platform
So I decided just to try to take that platform from Android Studio
So I copied folder android-34 from
C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms
to C:\Users[User]\android-sdks\platforms
and also folder android-34 from
C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images
to C:\Users[User]\android-sdks\system-images
After that Eclipse SDK Manager showed me that Android 14 platform is installed
and I was able to choose the Android 14 build target in project properties.
But the build failed, the console shows message
E/ResourceType(10564): ResTable_type entry count inconsistent: given 1, previously 1314
and a lot of similar messages like
... res\layout\activity_help.xml:1: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'android'
for different attributes
also
in Problems tab I have a lot of messages
R cannot be resolved to a variable
I just don't know enough about Eclipse ADT to continue this brave experiment further so any ideas are welcome :-)

Honestly so much has changed since Eclipse/ADT (about 10 years now) that I would start with a clean/empty project from Android Studio and port over the source code and resources and then working through the errors/bugs that you encounter (permissions/file access/unsupported libraries). Be aware that Google Play Services ended support for Lollipop (5.0) recently

Switching to Android Studio is the only way to go. You can try to start with an early Android Studio version (e.g. v2.0). AFAIR those versions had an importer that could convert Eclipse based projects to Android Studio.

Switching to Android Studio is probably the quickest way to solve this. Eclipse ADT is outdated, and it doesn’t fully support newer SDKs like Android 14, which is why you’re seeing all these errors. Android Studio has tools to help fix compatibility issues automatically, and it uses Gradle, which is now the standard for Android builds, making it easier to manage updates and dependencies.
Creating a new project in Android Studio and copying your code over will save you time in the long run and make it much easier to keep up with future Android updates. This way, you’ll have better support for new features, and the project will be set up in a way that Google’s tools are optimized for.

I did not ask for advertising of Android Studio  :-)

@Aleksey All the same this is the correct answer. As a top answerer of Eclipse questions I can say that no one has asked questions about using Eclipse ADT for years - you aren't going to get any help here as no one uses it anymore.

@Aleksey, You like it or not bro, this is the truth. I gain nothing advertising Android Studio. Beside, it's free, open source. You can be stubborn and keep using Eclipse ADT and face issue, completely your decision bro. But I think that time should be given in creating something new, rather than fixing an unfixable issue.

I asked the question about Eclipse ADT and Android SDK. I don't know why all these people write here about Android Studio. This is definitely off-topic here. Actually besides Android Studio there are several different IDEs to make apps for Android. I have no idea why all these people suddenly got focused on Android Studio. Is it because it belongs to the same monopolist which owns the OS and the only marketplace for apps ?

Only one word I got for you bro - LOL
